# Calcular promedio arreglos PSEINT

Tags: pseint

¿Cómo podría modificar este programa para pueda calcular el promedio a través de arreglos? sin que después de que ingrese el numero aparezca el mensaje aprobado/desaprobado

```
 Algoritmo actividad4
    //Hacer un programa para calcular el promedio de 3 notas; si el promedio es mayor
    //que 10.5 mostrar aprobado de lo contrario mostrar desaprobado.
    Dimension notas[3]
    Para i<-1 Hasta notas[3] Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "Ingrese el valor de la nota"
        leer  notas[i]
        
        
    promedio = (notas[1]+[2]+[3]) / 3
        
Si promedio > 10.5 Entonces
        Escribir "Aprobado"
SiNo
        Escribir "Desaprobado"
Fin Si
        
    Fin Para
    
FinAlgoritmo
```

Comment: El fin para, no esta muy lejos del para? vos queres repetir todo ese codigo 3 veces, o solo pedir las notas 3 veces?

Comment: si quiero usar para el PARA para poder repetir 3 veces la nota en lugar de escribirla una por una

Comment: Claro... pero tu para, incluye montones de cosas que no queres.. vos que lineas queres repetir.. todas? o solo donde pedis las notas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Algoritmo actividad4
Definir numNotas como Entero
numNotas <- 3
Dimension notas[numNotas]

Para i<-1 Hasta numNotas Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Escribir "Ingrese el valor de la nota #", i
    Leer notas[i]
Fin Para

promedio = (notas[1]+notas[2]+notas[3]) / 3

Si promedio > 10.5 Entonces
    Escribir "Promedio aprobatorio de "
SiNo
    Escribir "Promedio reprobatorio de "
Fin Si
Escribir promedio
```

FinAlgoritmo

Con este código bastara, el problema que tenias es que tambien repetías 3 veces sacar el promedio e imprimir la respuesta.